# Install eclipse for java

Tags: java, eclipse, c++, eclipse-cdt

I have eclipse kepler cdt for c++ but I want to download eclipse for java and keep eclipse cdt
I mean use eclipse for both Java and c++

Comment: I don't understand where is the question? You can just download eclipse for java and use it keeping one more eclipse for c++ in another folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse is normally a standalone program. Go a head download the eclipse for java save it to a different location and always navigate to the directory to run it

Answer (score -1):

In my experience Netbeans is a lot faster on Ubuntu than Eclipse. But you should be able to install a Java extension for Eclipse?
No answer to be found here? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EclipseIDE

Comment: I can download eclipse for java but I want to have 2 eclipse IDE's
one for Java and the other which I already have CDT